# How to create a 2D Map to use in a Android Game?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a program that can make a 2D map to use in a Android Game. How I can import this map (that can be in what format? `.bin`, `.fmx`?). I was reading about the Tiled Map Editor.

Answer (score 1):

TMX maps can be created using programs like [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/). It is possible to use 2D maps in Android without using a game engine like [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/). However, this means that you will have to write your own code for parsing, displaying, moving and interacting with them. Therefore, it is much simpler to use a game engine which already provides means for you to do this, like AndEngine does. You could also look at [libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the program [tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/). If you want a tutorial on how to make a map with tiled check out [ray's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d) tutorial for ios. The map creation will be the same for android. To implement with your android map, check out [cocos2d-x] which is now available for android. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Mobile Atlas Creator for Creating Offline Maps for Android

[click](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/)