# What is best best approach to make a 2D map that will be a level selector in android using native android components?

Tags: android, android-layout, 2d, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I need to make a 2d map which lays out levels for a android game. It is low budget and I need to make it with native android components.

The map goes to a finite number of levels so I do not have to generate the map dynamically and using the technology suggested in http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/smart-2d-levels-map.267394/
will be a bit of a over kill.

I also got a heap of motivation from [How to create a 2D Map to use in a Android Game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870175/how-to-create-a-2d-map-to-use-in-a-android-game) as they said that it is possible to achieve what I need without a engine.

All I am enquiring about is if I should make a scroll view with a relative layout inside and then align the real buttons relative to each other in px (as dp will make that the images will not line up in all cases as the background which is a image is in px) or should I approach this completely differently.

My biggest concern with my initial thought out approach is that the different screens will mess with the locations of the buttons and that if I make everything px that the screen will be to small for high density screens.

I have considered to make different layout files for the different screen sizes but before I start developing I thought that it will be best to get another view point from the community

Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played around with using a relative layout and this seems to work on all screen sized after I set the height and width to static dp values. This makes the ratio constant and makes the solution acceptable on any screen size